# command line backup script

Tags: windows, command-line, backup, 7-zip

I need a batch script which does the following:

- adds contents of the current directory to an archive
- includes datetime in the filename
- does not include previous backups

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my attempt. Works but can be improved:

```
@echo off

FOR /F "tokens=* USEBACKQ" %%F IN (`date /t`) DO (
SET mydate=%%F)

set h=%TIME:~0,2%
set m=%TIME:~3,2%
set s=%TIME:~6,2%
set mytime=%h%_%m%_%s%

7z.exe a -r "%mydate%%mytime% Backup".7z -x!*.7z
```